# How to eliminate button shift in a tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter

in a tkinter gui (python 3) when a button is pressed there is a little shift right and down to simulate button-pressed effect, so the text on the button moves.
I need to eliminate this shift to obtain a motionless button.
Please help me.
Many thanks.

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
top.geometry('480x320')
top.configure(bg="black")

def helloCallBack():
   print( "pressed")

B = Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack, highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
B.place(x=50, y=50, width=100, height=100)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think this is probably what users expect (unless you are hiding its button nature). Tkinter is just a wrapper for Tk, the underlying library doing this (which is not in python), so that behavior is probably attributable to a deeper level and hence might not be changeable.

Comment: Maybe it is platform specific, I can't reproduce on osx

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `relief=FLAT` option. But that makes the button look like a label. See [this example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_relief).
So maybe `relief=GROOVE` would be better.

Comment: Many thanks Roland but this attribute don't elimine the shift.

Comment: Well, then it's probably as @DarthCadeus said in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a label instead of a button, and then use `bind` rather than the `command` attribute.

```
def helloCallBack(event):
   print( "pressed")
...
B = Label(top, text ="Hello", highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0)
B.bind("<1>", helloCallBack)
```